# Ability to monitor sound volume when headphones are used?

Tags: applications, root-access

I am curious if there is a way to log sound volume when headphones are used to play music.

I am doing a research project to quantify hearing loss resulting from listening to music on phones and need a way for people to provide stats about how loud and how long people are listening to music with their headphones on an android phone.

Is this something I would need to root the phone to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you **do not need root** to monitor the volume.

If you're looking to develop an app for this project, you're in the lucky place because you do **not** need to know Android programming to deploy this.

There's an app called [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en), which allows you to automate your device, but also **allows you to export apk's** (Android applications)!

Screenshot:

[image: Tasker]

With Tasker, you can set up a profile to detect "volume changed" and send it to your webserver (or store it locally).

The navigation is `Profiles Tab > "+" on bottom right > Event > Variable Set > Media Volume: %VOLM` and **create a new task to send it to your webserver** via `Action > Net > HTTP Post`.

After that, download [Tasker App Factory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory&hl=en) (separate app), and move your profile into a new project by long-pressing on the home icon, clicking "New Project", and naming it. You'll have to drag your profile and task to the new project, and set an icon for your project. Finally, you'll be able to long-press on your project, hit Export, and hit "As App".

Good luck with your project!

Comment: awesome thank you this is even better than the answer I was hoping for!! (incidentally is there an equivalent app for iphone?...or at least, do you know if it is possible to do this sort of monitoring on iphone). thanks again!!!

Comment: This sounds insufficient for the OP's needs because it records only what the volume slider is set to, not how loud the sound really is. For example, you might be listening to loud music at low volume or quiet music at full volume, and they would produce the same sound level.

Comment: @leeroid no problem! You're in the wrong place for iPhone advice, but from what I know there is no way to tell what the volume level is from a sandboxed iPhone app. Automation apps are also limited in the iPhone world, because they don't have access to system resources. I may be wrong though, volume level may be accessible from a global variable in Swift/Xcode. I do acknowledge Dan Hulme's concern, if iPhone support is a must, an idea would be to wire up a Raspberry Pi between the headphone/jack to measure dB levels.